# PHP Beanstalk with laravel permission denied on storage/framework/cache

Tags: php, linux, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've deployed my Laravel 5.1 app using Amazing Beanstalk and after repeated usage I eventually get this error.

```
"file_put_contents(/var/app/current/storage/framework/cache/d4/d7/d4d77eddeb64100f6da8f8b601a4631b): failed to open stream: Permission denied"
```

In my .ebextensions config file I've tried adding this command to deployment but it does not solve the problem since the files seem to get created after deployment as the site is browsed.

```
container_commands:
  "02-chmod-storage":
    command: "cd /var/app/ondeck;  chmod -R 777 storage"
```

How can I fix this permanently?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_chmod_storage.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
      cd $EB_CONFIG_APP_CURRENT
      su -c "chmod -R 777 storage" $EB_CONFIG_APP_USER
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ACL permissions on */storage* allowing rwx access for **root** and **webapp** (or username of running web server):

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_setfacl_storage.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      echo "Setting ACL permissions for /storage..."
      setfacl -Rdm u:root:rwx,u:webapp:rwx /var/app/current/storage
      setfacl -Rm u:root:rwx,u:webapp:rwx /var/app/current/storage
```